# Hide some system tray icons uncollapsed

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

There are some icons that I never want to see in the notification area, for instance "safely remove hardware".

How do I filter the icons I can see without the having the "expander arrow" that comes up after a number of icons?

[image]

If I enter taskbar settings and I click and toggle "always show all icons in the notification area" to have it off, I will be able to turn off some icons, but then it seems like I have to live with that arrow button.

Comment: Right click on the Taskbar, choose Unlock. Then you can see the notification icon without the arrow. See if that works.

Comment: There is no unlock, just "lock all taskbars".

Comment: That seems strange. Unlock is just not locked.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but quite complicated for just getting rid of a little
character on the traybar. I found this post on a boring day, so here
is a solution, requiring some programming using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

A pre-requisite is to enter Taskbar Settings by right-click on the taskbar,
click "Select which icons appear on the taskbar"
and set to On "Always show all icons in the notification area".
You will now remove from the traybar the icons that you don't want to see.

You will need to download the AutoHotkey script
[TrayIcon.ahk](https://gist.github.com/tmplinshi/83c52a9dffe65c105803d026ca1a07da)
from Github and put it in the same folder as the following scripts.
To run a script after installing AutoHotKey, put it in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test.

First script will just list all the programs in the traybar.
You may press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the displayed
text, so you can then copy-paste the exact names of the processes
in the next script.

```
test := TrayIcon_GetInfo()
Loop, % test.MaxIndex()
  str .= test[A_Index].process "`n"
MsgBox, %str%
ExitApp
#Include TrayIcon.ahk
```

Put the names of the processes whose icons you wish to remove
in the following script with a comma as delimiter. Avoid names that
may belong to Windows programsn:

```
remove_array := "Prog1.exe,Prog2.exe,Prog3.exe"
Loop, parse, remove_array, `,
{
    oIcons := TrayIcon_GetInfo(A_LoopField)
    TrayIcon_Remove(oIcons[1].hwnd, oIcons[1].uid)
}
ExitApp
#Include TrayIcon.ahk
```

Most processes owning the icons continue to work in the background.
If you wish to return all the removed icons, start Task Manager,
kill `explorer.exe`, then restore it using the menu
*File > Run new task*, enter `explorer.exe` and click OK.

You may run the second script whenever you wish to reduce that traybar,
but the icons will fully return after a reboot.

To have it run automatically on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.
In this case, you might want to add a small delay before it starts
working, by adding at its beginning a
[Sleep command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm)
like this:

```
Sleep, 2000     ; The time to pause in milliseconds
```