# How to remove icon of a running program from system tray in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit

Any way to do this, maybe through registry editor? What I'm trying to do is, I have a time tracking/keeping software running the whole time (to keep track of what my kids do on the pc), but the problem is the app's icon can always be seen on the system tray.. so my kids can just right click on the icon and disable the app lol.

I believe there should be a way through regedit to hide the app's icon from being displayed in the system tray.. but I have no idea how

Comment: A function as you describe would be part of the App programming. Ask the software vendor if you can hide the icon.

Comment: Meaning it's not within the power of registry editor to do this? I've always thought regedit have some kind of overriding power when dealing with icons in taskbar/system tray/desktop etc

Comment: There is not likely a registry setting in the App you describe.  Windows does not hide Vendor App icons.

Comment: My journey of a thousand miles to do this through regedit have been futile then. My grandmaster will be disappointed.

Comment: Software has areas in the code regedit can alter variable there. It is not and never been black magic. So unless the Software vendor can help you, you are out of luck.

Comment: No registr entries that can help you. You can check this: https://superuser.com/questions/1707389/hide-some-system-tray-icons-uncollapsed But let's be honest, if a software of this kind doesn't have an option to remove the icon in its settings, I'm not sure I'd recommend using it.

Comment: What if you run the app as Administrator, and don't give the little ones that password?